# Issue with saving canvas data to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, canvas

I am creating a web application using HTML5  canvas to draw images ( like paint web ), I try to implement the "undo" (ctrl+Z) and "redo" features and here I am facing a strange problem with an array of canvas elements.
Sometimes, when I hit ctrl+Z to undo, a blank image appears, however the data is in the array and I point to the correct element (because when I play with undo/redo I manage to have the corrects images in the right order).

If you can have a look at the following code I would be grateful, I've spent a lot of time already and I'm not able to locate the problem... :-(

```
function Stack(firstImg , size) {
    var drawStack = new Array();
    var stackIndex = 0;
    var stackTop = 0;
    var stackFloor = 0;
    var stackSize = size; 

    drawStack[0] = firstImg;

    this.add = function() {
        drawStack[++stackIndex%stackSize] = cvs.toDataURL("image/png");
        if (stackIndex >= stackSize) stackFloor = (stackIndex +1) % stackSize ;
        stackTop = stackIndex % stackSize;
    }

    this.undo = function () {
        if (stackIndex%stackSize == stackFloor ) return;
        clearCanvas();
        var tmpImg = new Image();
        tmpImg.src = drawStack[--stackIndex%stackSize];
        cvsCtx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0);

    }

    this.redo = function () {
        if (stackIndex%stackSize == stackTop) return;
        clearCanvas();
        var tmpImg = new Image();
        tmpImg.src = drawStack[++stackIndex%stackSize];
        cvsCtx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Any solution or workaround, I will take, thank you very much !!

Comment: javascript arrays have push, pop and shift. im not sure there's a reason to be doing all the modular division and indexing...

Comment: to anyone who is interested in this post. My code works, I just forgot the famous img.onload function... which results in blanks pictures in my applications

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented undo/redo functionality a few times and, while I cannot post the code for licensing reasons, I can give you some psuedocode that should demonstrate how simple undo/redo actually is:

first, you need two arrays. call these "undo" and "redo".

Every time the state changes, push that state to the undo stack.

When the user presses ctrl-z (undo), pop the last saved state from the undo stack. push this state to the redo queue, and also make it the current state.

When the user presses ctrl-y (redo), pop the last saved state from the redo queue.

If either of the arrays begins to fill up past the # of states you want to save, use shift to discard the oldest state.

For references on push, pop, and shift, see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Also, you will probably find yourself wishing arrays had peek, so here it is:

```
Array.prototype.peek = function () {
    var theArray = this;
    var temp = theArray.pop();

    if (temp !== undefined) {
        theArray.push(temp);
    }

    return temp;
};
```

edit: there was a bug in my snippet, calling .peek() on an empty array would push undefined.

Comment: Thank you it sounds great i'll do it again from scratch